# Ajuda com Spring jdbcTemplate

Tags: hibernate, spring, spring-data

Eu criei uma classe:

```
package com.market.config;

    import javax.activation.DataSource;

    import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
    import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
    import org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate;
    import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.embedded.EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder;
    import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.embedded.EmbeddedDatabaseType;

    @Configuration
    public class BdConfig {

        @Bean
        public JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate(DataSource dataSource) {
            return new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
        }
    }
```

estou com esse error:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

e eu tenho dúvidas como fazer uma metodo para pegar esse dataSource configurado  no meu application.properties:

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://${MYSQL_HOST:localhost}:3306/market
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=
```

Answer (score 0):

Oi,

Você precisa configurar o datasource antes

Assim

```
 @Configuration
    public class BdConfig {


        @Bean
        public DataSource getDataSource() {
            DataSourceBuilder dataSourceBuilder = DataSourceBuilder.create();
            dataSourceBuilder.driverClassName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
            dataSourceBuilder.url("jdbc://blablabla");
            dataSourceBuilder.username("usuario");
            dataSourceBuilder.password("senha");
            return dataSourceBuilder.build();
        }


        @Bean
        public JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate(DataSource dataSource) {
            return new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
        }
    }
```

De qualquer forma dependendo da versão do spring data que estiver usando não precisa configurar o jdbctemplate manualmente, basta injetar ele no seu repository ou no service usando autowired assim

```
@Repository
public class MeuRepositorio {

    @Autowired
    JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;
```

Comment: Estou usando a versão 2. alguma coisa acho que é a mais atual, No caso eu só precisaria utilizar   @Autowired
    JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate; em uma classe DAO sem utilizar o datasource? vc poderia me dar um exemplo como ficaria essa utilização em um dao ?

Comment: Isso, basta fazer o '@Autowired', o ideal é que fosse em um '@Repository', que é chamado por um '@Service', tem um exemplo de uso do Jdbctemplate usando '@Autowired' aqui https://spring.io/guides/gs/relational-data-access/